# Where to dispatch fetch for data load?

Tags: react-redux

I'm getting started with using Redux, and currently have a working use of action creators, reducers etc. My container is set up to mapStateToProps, and everything is showing up on our pages as expected.

One thing I was hoping for advice for was where to actually dispatch the fetch action creator. The data is retrieved via an API call and gets formatted and displayed on the page. Right now I have the dispatch in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   ...
   props.dispatch(fetchInfoBlah(someParamsFromRouter))
}
```

This works, but I just put it there as a guess since most examples I've seen online trigger fetches as a result of some trigger/event, rather than just the fact that the component needs to load. I was previously making the API call from the componentDidMount().

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: componentDidMount is the place.  more here: https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/

Comment: I am currently doing this in `componentDidMount()` ... is there a reason you switched?

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the situation.

If you need to display data/info when component first loaded, call it from constructor.

If you need to display/update data/info when user interact with your app, call it according to user actions.

#### componentDidMount() vs constructor()

`componentDidMount()` runs after `render()`. So componentDidMount is used when you want to make sure its run after component is rendered once. This helps reminding to set initial state data otherwise there's no data for `render()`

`constructor()` is the same as `componentWillMount()` and runs before render(). When calling inside constructor, the fetch response is available either before or after `render()`

Comment: Why the constructor over `componentDidMount()` though?

Comment: @chapeljuice , just added explanation for componentDidMount() vs constructor()

Answer (score 0):

When I need to fetch data asap I always use `componentDidMount()`.

Mainly because I bookmarked this article which I've been referencing quite a bit and it's seemed to work out for me so far!
https://engineering.musefind.com/react-lifecycle-methods-how-and-when-to-use-them-2111a1b692b1